# text input in datepicker

Tags: datetime

how can i add some default text in my datepicker ? I want to add text in the box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit you field in Manage fields section of your content type and set default value for that date field.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.
I added this code screen.js

jQuery('#datepicker_id').attr("placeholder", "text");